# How to add ng-click event on only last item of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I want to add click event on **only last item** of list of items.

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="myFunction" >{{item.name}}</li>

    $scope.myFunction = function(){
     // logic here...
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="$last && myFunction()" >{{item.name}}</li>
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/8qkynso8/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end:

```
<header ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  Header {{ item }}
</header>
<div class="body">
  Body {{ item }}
</div>
<footer ng-repeat-end ng-click="doStuff">
  Footer {{ item }}
</footer>
```